# Command line argument for lengthy command

Tags: invocation

I keep a `sys.md` file where I record a dated entry of every modification I make to my system (mostly installations of software, sometimes configuration changes) and based on an old [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17538697) [link about a did file](https://theptrk.com/2018/07/11/did-txt-file/) I came up with the idea of an alias that would auto-insert the date and set me up with exactly the prompt I want for an entry to `sys.md`.

This command opens my `sys.md` file and inserts the date and the bottom:

```
nvim +'normal Go' +r!date' ~/notes/sys.md
```

I want to copy that line, paste it below, replace it with `-`'s as a markdown h2 heading, insert a new line and begin it with a dash-space `-_` to start a bullet.

```
yypVr-o-_
```

However,

```
nvim +'normal Go' +'r!date' -c 'yypVr-o-_' ~/notes/sys.md
```

does not work. How can I auto-execute those commands?

Comment: You mean something like this: `vim +'$pu_|r!date' +'norm yypVr-o-_' foo.txt`? I think you are missing your `:normal` command. See `:h :norm`

Comment: @PeterRincker If you'd put that as an answer I'll accept it. It worked.

Comment: @PeterRincker: what does the $pu_ do?

Comment: I had to eliminate $pu_ from the command and reform it as `nvim +'normal Go' +'r!date' +'yypVr-o-_' ~/notes/sys.md` Because the BASH aliasing system didn't like your `$pu_`, but the `+'norm <commands>'` synax was what I was looking for anyway. Thank you!

Comment: Using `:put` with the black hole register, `"_`, will create a blank line. Providing a range of `$` will mean we put a blank line at the end of the file. See `:h :range`, `:h quote_`, and `:h :put`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yypVr-o-_` are not ex-commands, but normal. Use `:normal` to execute normal commands.

```
vim +'normal Go' +'r!date' +'yypVr-o-_' ~/notes/sys.md
```

For more help see:

```
:norm
:h -c
:h :r!
```